# How do i get backpress when user swipe left to right in CupertinoPageRoute?

Tags: dart, flutter, navigation

currently i use CupertinoPageRoute to navigate any screen.

but issue is that when android user swipe left to right i couldn't get returned data.

and when i try to use WillPopScope to get backpress page sliding is stop working.

how do i get backpress in CupertinoPageRoute;

this is my code

this is my redirect method:

```
void redirect(Widget page, BuildContext context) async {
    var result = await Navigator.push(
        context, AnimationPageRoute(page: page, context: context));
    setState(() {
      showBottomNavigation = true;
    });
    return result;
  }
```

this is my Route Class:

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimationPageRoute extends CupertinoPageRoute {
  Widget page;
  BuildContext context;
  AnimationPageRoute({@required this.page,@required this.context}) : super(builder: (BuildContext context) => page);

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,) {
    return page;
  }
}
```